# How to get random photos from gallery without picker Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I need to extract some random images from gallery without the picker option. Please be clear that I don't want to open picker for this, just extract images if user tapped the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dart:io to get the files in a directory and display one of the image files in the directory.

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
var files = io.Directory("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera").listSync();
final _random = new math.Random();
var idx=  _random.nextInt(files.length) ;
var file = files[idx];
//TODO display the file.
```

Comment: i want to get some random photos from the gallery and upload to firebase storage. so i just need to have an array of random photos or video from gallery.